# Share login information between two servers

Tags: iis, coldfusion, dns

I have an intranet application running coldfusion 10 and a server set up for exchange email that runs OWA 2007. Is there way to share credentials so that if a user is logged into the intranet server they will not have to log into OWA?

Comment: If its intranet applications using Windows authentication will solve your problem. You may implement authorization logic if you want to allow selected people to use these applications.

Comment: I have tried making a user account that access to every inbox, and passing that in the url. But, all the users had access to eachother's mailboxes. The issue is they are on two separate servers, so once the user is logged into the coldfusion intranet application, I cant pass those credentials on to OWA